# Codeigniter the files is not uploading in my local.Where as it is working fine in live server

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-3

The code is working fine in my live server bbut when i take down  the files tom my local where i am using linux with lampp installation it is not uploading the file .

[image]

**my controller code**

```
  if ($_FILES['ss_image']['name']) { 
            $data['ss_image'] = $this->doUpload('ss_image');
        }
```

**my doupload method**

```
     function doUpload($file) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/ss_inventory';
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file))
            {
              $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Sysops : Upload  Inventory ';

                $this->loadViews("upload_form", $this->global, $error , NULL);
            }
            else
            {
              $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
              return $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="ss_image">File input</label>
                  <input type="file" id="ss_image" name="ss_image">

                  <p class="help-block">Upload Jpg or png or jpeg </p>
                </div>
```

I have tried changing  different views in doupload method but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the directory has write permission using `ls -l`  command in terminal.